# What's wrong with this Facebook Graph JSON call?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull photos from an album (timeline) on Facebook and insert them into a list on a website but it's not grabbing all the photos.

I am using the ?limit=xxx in the URL to grab more than the first page but it still isn't working. Should I be using the paging ids and if so, what would be the syntax?

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/616894958361877/photos?limit=500&callback=?',function(json){
    $.each(json.data,function(){
$('<li></li>').append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + this.images[1].source + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"><a href=' + this.images[0].source + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>').appendTo('#timeline');
  });
});
```

This is the public facebook album in question:
https://goo.gl/ofrVjw

Comment: what errors do you see ?

Comment: It's only returning the first 50 photos and the timeline has many more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the limit is `100`. **[Check the graph explorer for that](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=616894958361877%2Fphotos%3Flimit%3D500&)**. The limit 500 is overridden with 100 and the api return pagination details.

Also in the above code snippet, while accessing `images` array there can be cases where images which might not have `images[1]` so try to handle that. Something like this

`((photo.images[1]) ? photo.images[1].source: ''`

In this demo **http://jsbin.com/nalusu/1/** you can see that the api returns 100 results.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you possibly give me the code example using my getJSON call above that would incorporate pagination to get more than 100, or perhaps a 'click for more' button that would call the next 100 for large galleries? I'm a relative noob and am not sure of the syntax.

Comment: I am sorry that can be quite a lot of work and I have many things going on already. I'll try to find some sample for you though. I'll post it here if i find one.

Comment: No problem. You time is greatly appreciated. This will work fine. I'll just tell my client to make his albums no bigger than 100 :)

Comment: I could pull off a very simple pagination if it helps. Here is the demo http://jsbin.com/nalusu/2/ It's not perfect but its a start.

Comment: do you understand the graph api access_token thing? You can see that your demo has stopped working and I'm always facing this situation... my json calls work for a while then it just stops working and I think it's related to tokens but I don't know how to "permanently" fix this.